# Find the Most Common Word (substring) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Ok, so I have a column with names of databases various state affiliates use.  Like so:

```
Filemaker
Access, Google Docs
Access, PT Avenue
Salesforce CRM
Microsoft SQL Server
iMIS
PT Avenue, Excel
Access, PT Avenue
Private Database
Google Docs, Constant Contact
Google Docs, Filemaker
Excel
Google Docs
Excel, MemberPlanet
```

I want to produce the most commonly used database.  The trick is that some of these states use multiple databases, which are listed in the same cell.  I tried using [this formula](https://exceljet.net/formula/most-frequently-occurring-text):

```
=INDEX(B5:F5,MODE(MATCH(B5:F5,B5:F5,0)))
```

Using that formula would produce the answer "Access, PT Avenue" when the real answer I want is "Google Docs".  Assuming multiple databases will always be separated with a comma, is there a way to return just the single most occurring database (that's called a substring, right?)?

Comment: I don't think this is achievable with a single formula. You may have two workarounds: split the data (first split your entries to different columns, then create a single list from them) OR use a macro.

Comment: You are trying Formula find the most occurred word in row and in fact your text doesn't have any !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution similar to what Máté Juhász suggested in a comment.  It's a few steps, but they're simple and don't require complicated formulas; Excel does all the heavy lifting.

- Split up the data.  Since the entries are comma delimited, just highlight the data and use Text to Columns, based on commas.  That gave me columns A and B, below.  Note that Text to Columns overwrites the source values, so if you need to preserve them, just work with a copy/paste version of the data.

[image]

- There's a space after each comma that needs to be removed so that the names aren't different due to a leading space.  In C3, I used:

  ```
  =TRIM(B3)
  ```

  and copied that down the column.  I added "Database" as a column label in A1 and C1, which are the source data for the next step.
- I used a pivot table on each of the A and C ranges, and stuck them one under the other in column A.  It's some quick drag and drop, and few few preference settings:

[image]

- I combined the results in column D with Copy and Paste-Special Values (a simple Copy/Paste will work, but this eliminated the borders).  That produces one list with the counts from each column.
- I used that to produce a new pivot table to consolidate the list with SUM.  That's all of the database counts in a single list.
- If the list is short, you can eyeball it to see the result (the pivot table sorts the names alphabetically).  If there's a long list and a chance that there could be a tie for the maximum, you could copy and past the result, then sort it.  I pulled the result shown under the pivot table with this formula (which will provide just the first max database if there's a tie):

  ```
  =INDEX(G21:G31,MATCH(MAX(H21:H31),H21:H31,0))
  ```

  This finds the MAX value in the SUM column, uses MATCH to identify the row, and uses that result to select the database name from the left column.

Comment: I don't suppose there is a way to put all of that into a single formula?  I've got a pretty massive, complicated sheet that I'm doing a mail merge with and I'm at the maximum number of merge fields.  I can't really add more columns.

Comment: @OzzyKP, there probably is a way to do this with one monster formula.  This solution occurred to me as a no-brainer way to get to the result without having to figure that out (or debug it or verify that it is working as expected).  If you don't want to see the intermediate steps, copy and paste the data to a new sheet (a few mouse clicks).

Answer (score -1):

[image]

**How it works:**

*I'm assuming that you have data in `A2:A15`.*

- Select Data and perform `TEXT to COLUMN` to split them using `COMMA` as `delimiter`.
- Write this formula in `B2` & fill down.

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)`

- Enter this **Reverse Lookup formula** to get the result.

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$15,MATCH(3,$B$2:$B$15,0))`

**N.B.**

- Logically Text Access & Google Docs both has same occurrence, but since Access comes first so the Formula pick it.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: You might have misinterpreted the question.  This is like a survey, where the responses each contain one or more database apps that the affiliate uses.  The responses (col A) can be a single app, or several apps separated by a comma.  Each mention of an app counts as `1`, and multiple apps can be reported in any order.  Once the delimited list is split into separate columns, there's no guarantee that the 1st column will contain a comprehensive list of the apps reported.  (cont'd)

Comment: There can be apps in either column that aren't in the other column, and a particular app can appear in either column.  So essentially, the second column is a continuation or wrapping of the list.  To find the most reported app, the apps need to be counted in both columns to find the total times each was reported.

Comment: It looks like you're getting the same result the OP is trying to fix: "Using that formula would produce the answer "Access, PT Avenue" when the real answer I want is "Google Docs".  There's a total of 3 Access and 4 Google Docs.  BTW, watch out for the leading space in the second column after you split the data.  That drove me nuts for a while trying to figure out why the second column was being viewed as a different collection of apps and not having their counts consolidated.

Comment: @fixer1234, but if I try to count text before delimiter Access & Google both are 3 !!

Comment: Right, and then there's another Google after the delimiter, but no more Access.